# How to add number from file above bar in pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a bar plot drawn with pgfplot and reading values from a CSV file. Is there a way to add a number above each bar where the number comes from another column in my CSV file ?

Comment: Please provide the code of a small complete document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that we can compile and that illustrates your question.

Comment: @sure, I'll do it later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is, you can use `\addplot[point meta=explicit]` (or `explicit symbolic` for non numeric meta data) and give the `table [meta=<column name>]`. For the nodes to show up in your plot, give the axis `nodes near coords` option.

I stole some code from the manual to make a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.csv}
x, y, type
0, 0.8, a
1, 0.50235, b
2, 0.86873, c
3, 0.99997, d
4, 0.04889, e
5, 0.54402, f
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
             nodes near coords,
             nodes near coords align={vertical},
             ]
\addplot[point meta=explicit symbolic] table [x=x, y=y, meta=type, col sep=comma] {table.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]